# Launch Tor I get: "The Tor executable is missing."

Tags: error

Launch Tor I get: "The Tor executable is missing." Why is it missing & how to replace?

Comment: What operating system do you use? How do you start Tor? Could you please add more details?

Comment: Probably antivirus false positives.

Answer (score 1):

AVG deleted my Tor executable a few days ago. Just download the package and unzip, etc., again and see what happens. I told AVG to ignore it. I haven't had a problem with any scans since then, although I still do not know why AVG picked up on it in the first place. I've been using Tor for a few years.

Comment: Many antivirus programs use a heuristic approach, and try to detect viruses based on how the code works. This sometimes generates false positives.